# What's "shine"?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Super Smash Brothers Mêlée (SSBM) is a popular fighting game of a series (the Super Smash Brothers franchise) with its own community and cult-following. Perhaps as a result of being around for so long (the game was released in 2001 and still thrives), the community has developed a lingo for the game. Commentators of a match use the term "shine" which seems to refer to a move. It seems to be a verb. What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Shine" is the nick-name and a verb coined by the community which refers to the initial physical hit of Fox and Falco's Reflectors as they are activated at point-blank.

Thus, "Shine-spike" refers to edge-guarding with Fox's shine and not Falco's, because Fox's shine can spike opponents off the stage downwards, whereas Falco's shine does not.

"Waveshine" usually refers to jump-cancelling out of the Reflector animation into a wavedash. Occasionally, it refers to wavedashing then shining.

"Triple-shine" refers to a combo of Falco's shine, usually hitting from the ground, then during his first jump, and ending with a shine during his second jump.