# Can Falco shine Fire Fox?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee, project-m

[Shine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/118236/46216) is the hitbox of Fox/Falco's reflector. [Fire Fox](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Fire_Fox) is Fox's up special move.

Fox can shine a Fire Fox or Fire Bird (in the case of Falco) with good timing as it comes toward him. But can Falco shine Fire Fox or Fire Bird? I theorize yes because shining gives 1 frame of intangibility, but it could possibly not if Fire Fox always outprioritizes Falco's shine. In practise, I think maybe my timing is off, like it is with Fox's shine vs. Fire Fox/Bird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is indeed possible for Falco to use his shine on opposing space animals' recoveries, but whether you should is quite another matter:

1. Falco's shine hits people upwards. If you're trying to ruin someone's recovery, hitting them up is not going to do much for that. Fox's shine is much more effective for this because it hits sideways.
2. The hitbox of Falco's shine is smaller than Fox's (either 14% or 25% smaller, I'm having a brainfart on which is correct). As a result, your spacing and timing both have to be that more precise. Being outprioritized is not a factor, as Falco's does more damage and so can trump more things.

This answer only applies to Melee; I know nothing about PM (which this question is currently also tagged as).

Comment: Shine full-hop back-air. If in air, shine bair/dair/Fire Bird for star KO.

Comment: I also think that there are angles or spacings that are impossible to shine against due to Falco's shine hitbox size, judging from a little tool-assisted testing.